# put 24 different books on 4 shelves, each shelf has at least one book. why my answer is wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

put 24 different books on 4 shelves, each shelf has at least one book(The books are put next to each other). How many ways?

The right answer is C(23,20)*24!, meaning the first divide the 24 slots into 4 groups and each group has 1 slot, we get C(23,20), then put 24 books into these 24 slots in order we get 24!. Therefore the result is C(23,20)*24!.

My answer is C(24,4)*4^20. I first choose 4 books and put them onto each shelf, I get C(24,4), then just put the rest 20 books which ever shelf, it should be 4^20. So my answer is C(24,4)*4^20.

Can anyone tell why my answer is wrong?

Comment: One way to see the right answer:  Order all of the books, of which there are $24!$ ways.  Then put the first four books on each of the shelves, so that each shelf has a book.  Then use stars and bars on the remaining $20$ books, of which there are $\binom{20+4-1}{20}=\binom{23}{20}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

You are overcounting.  Cases where the first shelf get books $a,b$ are counted once with $a$ among the first four and again with $b$ among the first four.  You are also undercounting by not accounting for the order of books on each shelf

Answer (score 1):

After the first four books are chosen, your way doesn't take into account in which order the rest of the books are *in each shelf*. Also, you don't distinguish which of the first four books go on which shelf. So, for instance, you count

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22
23 24
```

as indistinguishable from

```
11 10 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2
21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12
23 22
1  24
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Assume that the books are numbered from $1$ to $24$:
$$ 1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6\;7\;8\;9\;10\;11\;12\;13\;14\;15\;16\;17\;18\;19\;20\;21\;22\;23\;24$$
and put three separators between them (we have $23$ distinct places for positioning such separators)
$$ 1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6\;7\;8\,\color{red}{\perp}\,9\;10\;11\;12\,\color{red}{\perp}\,13\;14\;15\;16\;17\;18\;19\,\color{red}{\perp}\,20\;21\;22\;23\;24$$
then choose a random permutation from $S_{24}$
$$ 12\;2\;16\;4\;5\;6\;23\;8\,\color{red}{\perp}\,9\;18\;11\;1\,\color{red}{\perp}\,13\;15\;14\;3\;17\;10\;19\,\color{red}{\perp}\,20\;21\;22\;7\;24$$
getting four non-empty shelves. Every arrangement can be generated this way and the single steps are independent, hence we have $\binom{23}{3}\cdot 24!$ ways for accomplishing our task.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic stars and bars. Here is a general formula. If the order of the books doesn't matter we treat our $n$ shelves as bars and our $k$ books as stars. Then we have $n-1$ bars and $k$ stars. Thus if order of the books doesn't matter a general formula (where we may have a shelf with zero books on it) is $${n - 1 + k \choose k}.$$ If we need to put at least one book on a shelf then we have $n$ shelves  and we put $1$ book on each leaving us $k-n$ books (stars). Then we again have $${n - 1 + k - n \choose k -n }$$ where the order of the books on the shelves doesn't matter.

Alternatively if order matters we proceed in a similar fashion but first impose the ordering $k!$ on our $k$ books. So then we have $$k! \cdot {n - 1 + k \choose k}$$ with no restrictions (i.e. a shelf can be empty). And  $$k! \cdot {n - 1 + k - n \choose k - n}$$ for at least one book per shelf.

Comment: This concludes everything I need to know, thank you!

Comment: @DiWang no problem! Feel free to upvote/accept answer if you desire!